# Are boost coroutines faster than async operations from Boost.Asio? Or in what cases coroutines can be faster?

Tags: c++, optimization, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

In my case I have a server that processes plenty of sip calls (3000 simultaneously). It sends and receives SIP packets and a load of RTP packets (a packet per 20 ms).

Right now everything works asynchronously with callbacks by means of Boost.Asio.

I'm facing an optimization problem right now. Some things had been done to make it work faster (e.g. transition from dynamic allocation to pool allocation, changed the method of getting time, etc.), but acceleration was moderate.

Function profiler shows plenty of mutex_locks on top, so I think it has something to do with all these async calls. Browsing the web I found out about coroutines as an alternative to callbacks.
As I understand it, they make the code look more appealing and simple, while still maintaining an asynchronous nature.

But what about its **performance**? Will coroutines be faster than async calls and callbacks (at least in my case)?

Here's a screenshot from profiler:
[Profiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VszY9.png)

Comment: Instead of jumping into coroutines you should investigate origins of those mutex_locks calls.

Comment: Mutex_locks are called by io_service and strands.

Comment: Props to you for profiling, btw. Coroutines aren't inherently faster than event-based code, it depends on how they're used and how they fit the problem. Can you share any code?

Comment: There're lots of code. I can say that, there are async operations for receiving and sending packets. Steady timers are used in code. Maybe the problem is when I call async_wait with timers with a handler wrapped by strand and then these handlers call async_send_to/async_read_some also using strand to wrap their handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines are NOT faster than async calls because they're the same thing for Asio.

The chief difference is the way you write your composed operations: with coros you get the implicit coro stack as "closure", otherwise you have make classes to do the same. (Depending on *how* you did the latter, coroutines *might* end up faster if they do the work more efficiently. None of that would be the bottlenecks you profiled though)